# Json Key value match with text file attribute - Python

Tags: python, json, encryption

I have a huge json file in the below format, I wanna encrypt certain value from the particular tag without hardcoding the key or attribute names. But I am unable to map text values with json. Can somebody pls help me in resolving this?

```
    Output.txt
    {
        "layer1": [
            {
                "name": "abc", 
                "element": "Ether Element", 
                "inter": "Intrawork"
            }, 
            {
                "desc": "Some random desc", 
                "name": "cdf", 
            }
        ],
        "layer2": [
            {
                "cs": 12, 
                "Policy": "VODAFONED2GMBH48491-G0/3/1:10-NTE-INGRESS", 
                "class": "class-default"
            }
        ]
    }
    
    Encrypt.txt
    layer1  name
    layer2  class
    layer2  Policy
```

Code:

```
    import json
    
    f = open('Encrypt.txt','r')
    rows = []
    for line in f:
        row = line.split()
        row[0] = str(row[0])
        row[1] = str(row[1])
        rows.append(row)
    with open("Output.txt", 'r+') as json_file:
        d = json.load(json_file)
    for key, val in d.items():
        for i in rows:
            if i[0] in key:
                for j in d[key]:
                    if i[1] in j:
                        text = "encryptionkey"
                        val = text + str(val)
                        j[i[1]] = hashlib.sha256(val.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    with open('output_encrypted.txt', "w") as json_file:
        json.dump(d, json_file, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to read from Encrypt.txt the keys of the json in which the string needs to be encrypted.
In theory:

For every row of tags we go into each tag as deep as we can. if the current layer in which we are happens to be an array, we go into every array element and again, go as deep as we can until we reach the last tag of our current row. Either we make it to our desired tag or somewhere along the way a tag did not exist and we ignore that case.

This logic can be done recursively like this:

```py
import json
import hashlib

def encrypt(layer, row, i = 0):
    try:
        if i == len(row) - 1:
            if type(layer) is list:
                for entry in layer:
                    entry[row[i]] = hashlib.sha256(entry[row[i]].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            else:
                layer[row[i]] = hashlib.sha256(layer[row[i]].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            return

        if type(layer) is list:
            for entry in layer:
                encrypt(entry[row[i]], row, i+1)
        else:
            encrypt(layer[row[i]], row, i+1)
    except:
        pass


rows = []
with open('Encrypt.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.split()
        row[0] = str(row[0])
        row[1] = str(row[1])
        rows.append(row)


with open("my-json.json", 'r+') as json_file:
    d = json.load(json_file)

for row in rows:
    encrypt(d, row)

with open('output_encrypted.txt', "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(d, json_file, indent=4)
```

Here you can see the recursion beeing done in the encrypt function. there we pass the dictionary (or json) at first and the current row array and call the function again with the next layer or layers depending wether or not the currently accessed layer is an array.
The initial try except is in order to avoid non existent entries to break our code.

for instance if your json was to be modified like so:

```
{
    "layer1": [
        {
            "name": "abc",
            "element": "Ether Element",
            "inter": "Intrawork"
        },
        {
            "desc": "Some random desc",
            "name": "cdf"
        },
        {
            "desc": "Some other random desc"
        }
    ],
    "layer2": [
        {
            "cs": 12,
            "Policy": "VODAFONED2GMBH48491-G0/3/1:10-NTE-INGRESS",
            "class": "class-default"
        }
    ]
}
```

the code would cause errors without try/except. of course this can be replaced with appropiate if statements if desired.

Sidenote: the word "encrypt" here should be renamed to "encode" (hashing is a form of encoding, NOT encryption)